# Python ljust not displaying properly when including a lin

Tags: python, string, format

I am using Django creating a site for records for football teams, I have a "pretty" display with CSS, etc, but as a backup / old school version I am trying to have the code write the information to a basic .html file that is using rjust, ljust, etc to format text. In the code below if I remove the link code, and just display the string for the team's name everything lines up properly. Once I add the HTML for the link though the columns do not line up and are completely out of whack. What have I done wrong?

```
standings = Team.objects.filter(active=True).order_by('-wp')

output += '<pre>\n'  
output += '%s   %s   %s   %s\n' % (str('Rk').rjust(3), str('Team').ljust(50), str('W').rjust(2), str('L').rjust(2))
output += '%s   %s   %s   %s\n' % (str('--').rjust(3), str('----').ljust(50), str('-').rjust(2), str('-').rjust(2))

for row in mpi:
    the_team = "<a href=\"%s\">%s</a>" % (row.slug, row.name)
    output += '%s   %s   %s   %s\n' % (str(row.rank).rjust(3), str(the_team).ljust(50), str(row.won).rjust(2), str(row.lost).rjust(2))
output += '</pre>'
```

Comment: You realize the whole anchor tag in the_team variable is being justified and not just the value of row.name right? It would help to see the unexpected output though.

Comment: Right, if I include the anchor tag in the output line around the %s for team name, it will include the entire line including the spaces added by ljust.

Comment: You should consider using the `format` facility for string, for example `"foo {:>10s}".format("bar")`. Read up on it in the documentation!

Comment: Thank @hochl. I actually modified my code to the example below. I still am unsure how to get the anchor tag in there without linking the entire string and extra spaces. `output += '{:>3}   <a href="/ncaa-football/">{:<30}</a>   {:>2}   {:>2}   {:^9}   {:^6} ({:>3})   {:<40}\n'.format(row.rank, row.team.name, row.won, row.lost, mpi, sos, row.sos_rank, conference)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string `"<a href=\"%s\">%s</a>"` contains some characters that aren't rendered on browser,  you're formatting the source code, not the visualization.

Replace `str(row.the_team).ljust(50)` by `str(row.the_team).ljust(50+len(row.slug)+15)` because there are 15 invisible chars (ie. `<a href=""></a>`) plus the slug.

**Update:** You may want to remove some `str`. If some value is already a string, you didn't need to (re)transform it in string again.. You may also split long lines in shorten ones.

```
output = '<pre>\n'
output += '%s %s%s%s\n' % ('Rk'.rjust(3), 'Team'.ljust(50), 'W'.rjust(2), 'L'.rjust(2))
output += '%s %s%s%s\n' % ('--'.rjust(3), '----'.ljust(50), '-'.rjust(2), '-'.rjust(2))

for team in teams:
    link = '<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (team.slug, team.name)
    link = link.ljust(50 + len(team.slug) + 15)
    rank, won, lost = str(team.rank).rjust(3), str(team.won).rjust(2), str(team.lost).rjust(2)
    output += '%s %s%s%s\n' % (rank, link, won, lost)
output += '</pre>'
print output
```